# Alter schema of a table in spark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table in spark which looks like as below:

```
Table1
  col1                string
  col2                int
  col3                string
  col4                int
  col5                string
```

I have another table which looks like below:

```
Table2
    col1                string
    col2                int
    col3                string
```

I want to dynamically read schema of **table1** and alter the schema of **table2**, so that schema of both table should match(same column name and data type)

So finally table2 should look like below:

```
Table2
  col1                string
  col2                int
  col3                string
  col4                int
  col5                string
```

Is it possible to achieve using Pyspark?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can write your table into DataFrame and than get schema using:

```
val tableSchema = yourDataFrame.schema
```

You also can get it as list of table fields:

```
val tableSchema = yourDataFrame.schema.fields
```